# Upgrading rooted Galaxy Note II

Tags: rooting, updates, samsung-galaxy-note-2

So after about 3 years I have finally received and Android 4.3 to my Galaxy Note II. It downloaded it but refused to upgrade (probably because my device is rooted).

What do I do now?

Can I upgrade it anyhow? (also would like have it rooted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to return your device to complete stock.  Since you have rooted it, in Settings - About Phone it will list your device as Modified, so if that's the case, you won't be able to update.  Going back to 100% stock in Settings it'll say Official, at that point, you'll be able to update.

Comment: Thank you, does that mean that I have to then root it again?

Comment: Yes you would have to.